# User properties are not save between different sessions via Google Analytics 4 (events are sent with GTM server)

Tags: google-tag-manager

I implemented on my website GTM client, GTM server and Google Analytics 4.
Now I send events from GTM client to the GTM server from there it moves to the Google Analytics 4.
The event that is sent from the GTM client to the server contains event params and user properties.
All the user properties are sent to the Google Analytics 4.

Let me explain the situation I ran into.
Let's say I'm sending an event from the GTM server to google analytics, the event contains user properties.
Those user properties are user scoped and should be remain the same unless I change them again.
after a couple of hours after the current session ends I create another session (with the same user), however the user properties are not save although I do not run the over.
Also I saw that in the event data in the GTM server I get the same client_id and the same x-ga-js_client_id. (in the different sessions)

The implementation of the GTM server is by is by check the  Send to server container checkbox via "Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration"

Expected Behavior: I would like that the user properties will be saved between different sessions in Google Analytics 4 for the same user while the events are sent via GTM server

Steps to Reproduce:

- creating "Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration" tag in GTM client
- creating tag in GTM client that has this Google Analytics: GA4 tag
- set this tag with some user properties
- creating second tag in GTM client that has this Google Analytics: GA4 tag with no user properties
- create a session and send the first tag to GTM server
- wait few hours till session end
- create a session and send the second tag to GTM server